# Read Xml Element

Tags: c#, xml

I get an error when I try to read an element with ":"

```
<item>
  <guid isPermaLink="false">GUID</guid>
  <pubDate>Thu, 31 Oct 2013 07:18:00 +0000</pubDate>
  <atom:updated xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">2013-11-01T14:41:42.635+01:00</atom:updated>
  <category domain="http://www.blogger.com/atom/ns#">Wave3</category>
  <title>Vídeo</title>
  <description>Descriontion</description>
  <link>url</link>
  <author>noreply@blogger.com</author>
  <media:thumbnail xmlns:media="img" height="72" width="72" />
  <thr:total xmlns:thr="http://purl.org/syndication/thread/1.0">9</thr:total>
</item>


objItm.Element("media:thumbnail")
```

'"media:thumbnail"' threw an exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException'    System.Xml.Linq.XElement

Someone can help me?

Comment: `objItm.Root.Element()`

Comment: @Jonesy - That will still fail for elements that have a namespace (like `<media:thumbnail>`).

Comment: Could you post the entire XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set media Namespace first

```
XNamespace media = "img";
```

then use it like this

```
objItm.Elements(media + "thumbnail");
```

Answer (score 0):

tazyDevel's answer is nice but this is also working:

```
objItm.Elements().Where(p=>p.Name.LocalName == "thumbnail");
```

and you can use extension method `Single()` instead of `Where` if you are sure there is only one sub-element name *thumbnail*.